# Как решить ошибку "missing 1 required positional argument: 'message''

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Не получается сделать бота - постоянно вылазят баги. Либо выдаёт по 2 сообщения, либо ошибку  . В создании ботов новичёк, хоть и прошестрил всю документацию по созданию ботов, но комбинация 2-х библиотек как-то не получается.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import schedule
import time
import random
from threading import Thread

bot = telebot.TeleBot("***")

def schedule_checker():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def foo(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    url_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Перейти на опрос", url="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/***")
    keyboard.add(url_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Нажми на кнопку и перейди в опрос.",reply_markup=keyboard)
def chat(message):
    lines = open("test.txt", encoding="utf8").read().splitlines()
    randomline1 = random.choice(lines)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=randomline1)
    time.sleep(15)
    print(randomline1)

def doo(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    url_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Перейти на опрос2",url="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/***")
    keyboard.add(url_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Нажми на кнопку и перейди в опрос.2",reply_markup=keyboard)

def chat2(message):
    lines = open("test.txt", encoding="utf8").read().splitlines()
    randomline1 = random.choice(lines)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=randomline1)
    time.sleep(15)
    print(randomline1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    schedule.every(15).seconds.do(doo)
    schedule.every(15).seconds.do(foo)
    Thread(target=schedule_checker).start()

scheduler1=schedule.Scheduler()
scheduler2=schedule.Scheduler()
while True:
    scheduler1.run_pending()
    scheduler2.run_pending()
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Я не особо разбираюсь в telegram, но навскидку кажется, что декоратор `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])` нужен перед каждой из следующих функций: `chat`, `doo`, `chat2`, а не только перед `foo`.

Comment: `doo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'` Вот такую ошибку выдаёт

Comment: @Max Даже с декоратором перед этой функцией?

Comment: да, даже с ней..

Comment: @Max так ты же не передаешь обьект месседж в `schedule.every(15).seconds.do(doo)`

Comment: @oleksandrigo не понимаю каким образом передать туда месседж - пишет `message=` и при вводе любых данных говорит unresolved reference

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, что вообще должен делать ваш код. Насколько я понимаю, schedule ставит ваши функции на исполнение. Но они же являются обработчиками сообщения, и должны вызываться именно на приход сообщения. Зачем дополнительно запускать их по расписанию без прихода сообщения?